# How do you search for duplicate urls?

Tags: 7, uri

I have a problem with my navigation menu which may be related to a duplicate url.  A view or or other module may be creating the same url and a different view/module.  At this point, I do not know what the duplicate url is.  How would I search my site for duplicate or conflicting urls?  is there a module for that?

Would XML sitemap list duplicate urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP function `menu_get_item('path/in/question')` to determine more about what module is responding to the url.

If the path is an alias, you may need to use `drupal_get_normal_path($alias)`.

So if you use drush, you might run

`drush ev "print_r(menu_get_item(drupal_get_normal_path('path/in/question'))"`

That should return an array, which will likely have a 'page callback' element which will tell you the function (and hence, the module) that is handling that url.